# Can a function in rust return a struct with generic parameters that are populated inside the function?

Tags: rust

I have a struct called `config` that has generic type parameters `G` and `F` which have their own trait constraints. I have an additional `setup` function that takes in the same kind of generic type parameters and returns the `config` struct wrapped in a `Result` type:

**Code Sample 1**

```rust
struct GError;

struct config<G, F>
where
    G: Clone,
    F: Fn(G) -> i64,
{
    g: G,
    f: F,
}

fn setup<G: Clone, F: Fn(G) -> i64>() -> Result<config<G, F>, GError> {
    let g: G = 3;
    let f: F = |x: i64| -> i64 { x };

    let c: config<G, F> = config { g, f };

    Ok(c)
}
```

`setup` does not take in any formal arguments as the method in which `config<G, F>` struct is returned is through some internal logic that `setup` executes (which I have simplified). The returned `config<G, F>` is to be used elsewhere in the application as the rest of the application code depends on the generic nature of `config<G, F>

However I run into the following errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:13:16
   |
12 | fn setup<G: Clone, F: Fn(G) -> i64>() -> Result<config<G, F>, GError> {
   |          - this type parameter
13 |     let g: G = 3;
   |            -   ^ expected type parameter `G`, found integer
   |            |
   |            expected due to this
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `G`
                        found type `{integer}`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:14:16
   |
12 | fn setup<G: Clone, F: Fn(G) -> i64>() -> Result<config<G, F>, GError> {
   |                    - this type parameter
13 |     let g: G = 3;
14 |     let f: F = |x: i64| -> i64 { x };
   |            -   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `F`, found closure
   |            |
   |            expected due to this
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `F`
                     found closure `[closure@src/lib.rs:14:16: 14:37]`
```

I understand this error can be fixed by passing in some actual parameters that specify `G` and `F` e.g.

```rust
fn setup<G: Clone, F: Fn(G) -> i64>(someG: G, someF: F) -> Result<config<G, F>, GError> {
    let c: config<G, F> = config { g: someG, f: someF };

    Ok(c)
}
```

Given my business rules, I cannot take in parameters as all the logic is computed inside the `setup` function.

Is there a way to code this `setup` function such that I define what `G` and `F` are inside the `setup` function so as to satisfy `config<G, F>`?

Comment: [For your specific case](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=03c94df64b2e1c0a9b544dd60f6706d4) or [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=894f290732662010c539582b6ba9a0dd).

Comment: By the way, idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, fields and modules; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants.

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks for the comment and formatting. I took a look at the playground example and wondered if it were possible to have `G` still be generic. I see you have used `i32` as per the example I posted in the question, but `G` could literally be a `string` a `Vec` etc. Would I need to make functions for those? or does rust allow me to somehow keep `G` generic and at runtime specify the type.

Comment: *but `G` could literally be a `string` a `Vec` etc* — I doubt that, as the closure in `f` needs to know what `G` is in order to be implemented. Any implementation of the closure would need to know more information about `G` to even exist. Your function hard-codes `g` to be an integer number, so you are already pretty constrained.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll need to rethink this. Meanwhile thanks for the help and referral to another source.